# Weird networking behavior with a gateway between a switch and CMC module, on Dell VRTX equipment. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: networking, routing, switch, dell

### [Network Diagram:](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=weird-vrtx-networking#R5VphU%2BMoGP41%2FWgnCUmafqzV27sZ3XXU9fY%2B3dCEppxp6BBq6%2F76gwJpCHRXbbRanVGTF0LI8zwvvC%2FQA%2BP5%2BguFi9klyVDRC7xs3QNnvSAIPBDwf8LyKC2DMJKGnOJMmvyt4Qb%2FRMroKesSZ6gyKjJCCoYXpjElZYlSZtggpWRlVpuSwnzrAubIMtyksLCtf%2BOMzaQ1ibyt%2FU%2BE85l%2Bs%2B%2BpkglM73NKlqV6Xy8A082PLJ5D3ZaqX81gRlYNEzjvgTElhMmr%2BXqMCoGthk0%2B98eO0rrfFJXsSQ%2FEqh%2FsUX87yjgU6pZQNiM5KWFxvrWebr4PiRY8fjdj84Jf%2BvzyP8TYo2ITLhnhpm0LF4QsVD35TvGind1WpoosaaprKVExSHOkq4U1aFyMiMwRo4%2B8DkUFZPjBbB8qVeR1PfXoiFL42KiwILhkVaPlK2HgFWqBK%2FqUvP3IQJlfyBb1XaNrW9OGiR2sJLL5B1gsa8%2Fo%2B32vz61j4R%2BQodWmy8ruWzQytGYmOxRV%2BCecbCoI4tRX8trRaS864xZY4LzkhpTTgCg3PCDKMHeLkSqY4yzbSKCAE1Sc1mIfk4LQzXu13DXJogW0djmt6snWFwz6YzevqiWvnySeau55VG%2B51FXIdFpxOZn8PZux4S7GPhkzJ5yage8b7hHsR5RuOQj7kdHuSWC20Q2Tgy5HRLTG7Efj%2Bh9RhX%2BGvLtCFPOuCUI3Dx5g%2FIwOMX7G0euOn1q3TW%2BMh%2F0gCvlvdHwuOfitS4ZhYLrOnoOnahrEzlY7dUjdqx1kBp%2BLTM7lME5M73lP82BgkzUM%2Bn6ciMnQompKStZA0PPieDx2oM%2FE0FdbLwQFV6TCDBNROiGMkbnmplFQs2nR2xDHFBdFow%2FjzQ%2B3V4ySe9QoiZPEPwW8JKcww2jb85KUqGE%2Bw5STLHtQivG7bkznEoGwzOBCoDBf5yKH6peIrQi9r%2FpcVrKPO2VkjfM71QJA0pozfa251Tav8WNlmzVyGm1zKcgQyK%2FUACw1WBL4LamwWsgUb4rXYoptcufWicmcYoejWuCSW3XG6DlISDGjeN1nZIXovxWiD69HROQ7iBgAmwhOxf5MBFGXUc0rxymhI04Be8YpT5ZsaEn27vr2B7eML8cfQrzVCrN01o1sfWAGaiBxiBY4RNvF6BF8pLWJTuJoK74KExP%2FKGjhKn1EPbXfzB3ZMzd%2Fmfdlcs7%2F3khRBd4lyZYc6CAuRIw1ofwqZxvYbMsnc5aoRRYYDGxnCV1TLdjfWcCwS2d5T2mrHoIOMh0AO5O0cK7XcAUWGaxmLkSdSm2LEv5cUtSv445WZOp5fpKcdTSwx34rHolje2gfOMQKOhjZwdGuseiNj8OI1U6%2BjkSs5uJFHABLqjon7lyqydFKFRxSqk%2FIDD%2BmVNvjauQImV9tXO00y3tXYj1kTgjsnPBYxRq%2BnVhDO7TCZ9cjsb3519VDKDJuUk5xLnc8MzSFy0KkRtu9TzLt6Q1Q%2FqHelGPElQVFnvKC9ORFy8Zc6JXUvN9YZizQlO3OWRYwxWV%2Bu%2FGIk7AbKoNWnuhYXAL%2BaxHpWKCXe5%2FhcYHs%2By2UIxtl11JqO2l%2FEch2bKdAtsf84wJ5%2BIYg21GJAtleijoqkGPgiKhfC2R7NlUg21nhcYE8eEMl2yeILHDTJQ8xMh3gldlIHJzjt2kBqwqnJu69F4Vtu5ZFGwhEDgS0bd%2FV08CMbkDUQlZ21Vo9tc97xSaTYNhqaMcy7HPPRYQDd4d39cv6QK%2FbcxSRHaJ9%2B8al4F3x0F7GZcp1QTeu%2B2524aX%2F%2FOpIhTccGtjrM0%2F7nnICRqsn9bZhp9v0kR2y3UGKyZKL07u7GH2t7IBZhtd3l5UkfnQm%2FyOWHntwPWjvgjlCkvoEcNfRdWTHJNe3J1%2Fj%2BDs33szwZCJ6ekvmkJHvN0eGvOP8gufA3pWivmAW5bfbk9fSq7bH28H5%2Fw%3D%3D)

Here's the simplest way I know how to explain how the internal networking of this Dell VRTX works.

So, you have your 4 blades and your network switch module that have integrated remote management controllers, for the blades it's iDRAC and for the switch it's an internal OOB port that I can't actually physically plug into anything else.

According to Dell documentation these ports communicate with the CMC module of the enclosure. So technically the CMC is like a really dumb switch in some sense.

On my RT-N66U, I created 2 separate VLANs to segment the management interfaces and the rest of the interfaces of the switch and gave said interfaces 10.1.0.0 /24 addresses for management and a simple 169.254.255.1-2 /30 address set just to bridge the router and the switch module.

In the diagram I have the management interfaces set on a the range from .2 to .7, with a default gateway of 10.1.0.1. These all work fine.

However, the weird behavior is when I try to do static routes on the switch module.

The switch module supports layer 3 static routing. One primary issue is that in the Dell VRTX CMC, to access the web GUI I can set the IP for the OOB interface on the switch module. In this instance, it would show as 10.1.0.3 with a default gateway of 10.1.0.1. The odd thing is that for the switch, it sets the "ip default-gateway" property to this value and all of traffic ends up defaulting to this route which I don't necessarily want.

What i've tried:

- I remove the default-gateway and I add my own static routes. Problem is, 10.1.0.3 should technically be a directly connected interface so I can't really route back to 10.1.0.0 with any gateway that makes sense.
- If I do a default route of 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.1.0.1 which is the equivalent of a default gateway AND I add my other static routes for my VMs to get back out to my other networks, I am unable to access the web interface of the switch module for some reason. So here's a quick sample of what some configs look like and the behavior:

### Able to access web GUI but cannot ping/access devices in 10.2.0.0 subnet

---

```
show run
...
ip default-gateway 10.1.0.1
...

show ip route
...
S   0.0.0.0/0 [1/1] via 10.1.0.1, 00:01:15, oob
C   10.1.0.0/24 is directly connected, oob
C   10.2.0.0/24 is directly connected, vlan 3
C   169.254.255.0/30 is directly connected, gi0/1
...
```

### Add in a static route, lose access to web GUI but can ping/access devices in 10.2.0.0 subnet

---

```
show run
...
ip default-gateway 10.1.0.1
ip route 192.168.1.0 /24 169.254.255.1
...

show ip route
...
S   0.0.0.0/0 [1/1] via 10.1.0.1, 00:04:32, oob
C   10.1.0.0/24 is directly connected, oob
C   10.2.0.0/24 is directly connected, vlan 3
C   169.254.255.0/30 is directly connected, gi0/1
S   192.168.1.0/24 [1/1] via 169.254.255.1, 00:01:32, gi0/1
...
```

Lastly, if I remove the ip default-gateway and add my own static routes, the behavior is essentially the same as the first one above.

This embedded / internal port sharing setup is weird to me and I'm just wondering if I'm missing something stupid simple here. I've done a similar setup on a Cisco 3560E and Quanta LB6M and had no issues at all.

Thanks.

Comment: As I see it without full switch configuration you're likely routing everything on the switch, hence the results, as you can only have one L3 default gateway. If you can switch these networks (vlan3 and gi0/1) and then route them upstream on your router that would help.

Comment: @PeterZhabin what do you mean if I can switch them? The full switch config is unremarkable. https://pastebin.com/RZCUDkSy

Comment: Right now Vlan3 and gi0/1 are router interfaces, as you have IPs on them. If you remove these IPs, effectively converting them to switchports, your default route should affect only oob interface, the rest should be switched. You have to set up your endpoints (servers, DRACs, VMs) so that they use a router and not the switch as their default gateway though for this to work.

Comment: If I don't use routing interfaces then how will I be able to segment different networks into separate subnets for management purposes? Sorry I'm a newb to networking obviously. I'm trying to avoid the traffic going out through the 10.1.0.0 subnet for anything but remote management since it's 10/100 speed.

Comment: Well, according to your diagram you have some kind of router upstream, where you have created vlan3. You should do your routing there - you have vlan3 and default vlan interfaces on that router, and your switch module just feeds those vlans to that router either on separate physical ports, or on dot1q trunk.

Comment: The vlan3 is created on the switch module itself which is a layer 3 device, the only vlans that are technically created on the router are the routing interfaces.

Also I found this and I'm not sure if it applies to the situation, according to Dell:

-The system does not support forwarding IP traffic between In-band and OOB interfaces.

-The IPv4 address assigned to the OOB interface is not accessible through in-band interfaces and vice-versa.

-The OOB network IP address cannot be configured on the same subnet as the data network.

Comment: All right, let me try it this way - what's the purpose of having 169.254.255.0/30 in your setup? If this is just an uplink connection, consider making it switched instead of routed. If you're able to use 802.1q on the upstream side - use it and extend your vlans to the upstream router with 802.1q.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by the concept of using VLAN tagging, if I just make them switched then do I re-assign my IPs to actual devices starting from .1 instead of .2? Without a default gateway since it's switched?

Comment: Well, you assign .1 to your router (in fact its already assigned, I think), make it /24 (or whatever mask your devices use on their interfaces) instead of /30 and set default gateway on devices to your router IP.

Comment: So I can assign out 10.1.0.1-10.1.0.6 and so on to the devices and just have the gateway be the router which is 192.168.1.1?

Comment: No, OOB network should be left alone. What I mean is that I see no point in having IP addresses on a switch in Vlan3 and gi0/1. These (esp. 169.254.255.0/30) seem to be completely useless for me. In short, you should either use OOB and have internal switch working as L2-switch, or do a routing on internal switch as you do right now and manage in-band.